# How to get records based on particular column when multiple condition meets

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am trying to get the records, who are female (F) candidates, with greater than equal to 4 YOE and located in IN and CN and Salary greater than 50,000.

Two conditions am trying to meet here:

1. Higher the YOE, higher the preference
2. Between CN and IN, high preference are given to IN

It can be either be MySQL or PostgreSQL.

TABLE - 1 (ProfileDetails)

```
id  first_name  last_name email gender country_code

1       A           B       abc     F       IN
2       C           D       def     F       CN
3       E           F       ghi     F       IN
4       G           H       klm     F       CN
5       J           K       xyz     F       IN
6       X           Y       stu     M       IN
7       Z           O       cdf     M       UN
8       O           N       psq     F       CN
9       M           T       tql     F       IN
```

TABLE - 2 (SalaryDetails)

```
id  YOE     Salary

1   4       70000
2   10      60000
3   10      60000
4   11      55000
5   11      55000
6   5       70000
7   4       90000
8   6       55000
9   5       50000
```

Expected Output:

```
id      first_name      last_name       email       gender      country_code    YOE     Salary
1           A               B           abc           F             IN           4      70000
3           E               F           ghi           F             IN          10      60000
5           J               K           xyz           F             IN          11      55000
8           O               N           psq           F             CN           6      55000
```

This is the query I have tried so far:

```
select p.id
     , p.first_name
     , p.last_name
     , p.email
     , p.gender
     , p.country_code
     , s.YOE
     , s.Salary 
  from ProfileDetails p 
  left 
  join SalaryDetails s
    ON p.id = s.id 
 where p.gender = 'F' 
   and s.YOE >=4 
   and p.country_code in ("CN","IN") 
   and s.Salary > 50000
 order 
    by s.YOE DESC
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE ProfileDetails
    (id int not null, first_name varchar(7) not null, last_name varchar(7) not null, email varchar(7) not null, gender varchar(7) not null, country_code varchar(7) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE SalaryDetails
    (id int not null, company_name varchar(7) not null, YOE int not null, Salary int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (id));


INSERT INTO ProfileDetails
    (id, first_name, last_name,email,gender,country_code)
VALUES
    (1231, 'A', 'B', 'abc', 'F', 'IN'),
    (1233, 'C', 'D', 'cde', 'F', 'CN'),
    (1276, 'E', 'F', 'efg', 'F', 'IN'),
    (1298, 'G', 'H', 'ghi', 'F', 'CN'),
    (1401, 'I', 'J', 'ijk', 'F', 'IN'),
    (1408, 'K', 'L', 'klm', 'F', 'IN'),
    (1752, 'M', 'N', 'mno', 'M', 'UN'),
    (1121, 'O', 'P', 'opq', 'F', 'CN'),
    (1750, 'Q', 'R', 'qrs', 'F', 'IN'),
    (2113, 'S', 'T', 'stu', 'F', 'CN')
;

INSERT INTO SalaryDetails
    (id, company_name,YOE,Salary)
VALUES
    (1231, 'Voonix', 4, 55000),
    (1233, 'Realme', 10, 60000),
    (1276, 'Apple', 10, 60000),
    (1298, 'Iphone', 11, 55000),
    (1401, 'Samsung', 11, 55000),
    (1408, 'alpha', 5 , 70000),
    (1752, 'bets', 4, 90000),
    (1121, 'Gamma', 6, 55000),
    (1750, 'Theta', 5, 55000),
    (2113, 'Cosine', 4,55000)
;
```

Fiddle for MySQL - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0f009a

Comment: There appears to be a 1 to 1 correlation between the two tables, so why is salary stored separately?

Comment: I have got the table like that !!!!

Comment: @Strawberry can you help with the query to get the desired output ?

Comment: Also, given that you want an answer for Postgres or MySQL, it seems a little perverse to construct a sample in mssql

Comment: @Strawberry MySQL will be better

Comment: In that case, construct your fiddle in MySQL

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0f009a
I have attached in the Question as well  @Strawberry

Comment: @VivekS. Its absolutely Correct!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PostgreSQL**

```
select *
from (
    select *
        ,row_number() over (
            partition by s.yoe
            ,s.salary order by p.country_code in ('IN','CN')) r
    from profiledetails p
    inner join salarydetails s on s.id = p.id
    where s.salary > 50000
        and p.gender = 'F'
        and s.yoe >= 4
    ) t
where r = 1
```

Window Function References - [**1**](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/) & [**2**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-window.html)